# DNS Settings for Website and Mail Server

Tags: networking, email, dns, webserver, vps

I wanna built a simply html page and a mail server (iRedMail) on my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS from Digital Ocean and I bought domain from online.net.

Most guide is saying use glue records or host your DNS Server but after a week I am looking in tunnel vision I guess, I've no idea what I am doing.

VPN's hostname `mail.mydomain.com` (it was the guide, said configure from mydomain.com to foo.mydomain.com)

My DNS servers is `ns0/1.online.net`

My DNS Zone is like

> mydomain.com 86400 IN A 123.456.789.20
>
> mail 86400 IN A 123.456.789.20
>
> www 86400 IN A 123.456.789.20
>
> 123.456.789.20 86400 IN NS ns1.mail.mydomain.com.
>
> 123.456.789.20 86400 IN NS ns2.mail.mydomain.com.
>
> > (again, it was the guide, said you need to have glue records and I tried to do something, I don't have any clue am I going to the right way)
>
> mail 86400 IN MX 12 mydomain.com.

Comment: ...and now I cant connect to the server via ssh as `root@mydomain.com` it says "Could not resolve hostname kemalicecek.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known". I can only use ip instead of domain.

Comment: Would not be easier for you to just install WEBMIN or ISPCONFIG ?
Please go through this guide:https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-ubuntu-16.04-with-apache-php-myqsl-pureftpd-bind-postfix-doveot-and-ispconfig/
After setup complete you will not need GLUE records ;)

Comment: I tought it should be more easier but, I guess you are right. :) after a little bit pain, I'll built a perfect server on Debian :)

Comment: Follow that guide it will take you exactly about 2hours on super fast download speed, but my first time was 5hours, after you have a decent WEB panel and all, and you do not need to think about Terminal access etc, as long as the server is patched and always uptodate.

Comment: Do you have any specific suggestion panel? ispconfig, webmin or plesk? which one is easier or better, any opinion?

Comment: For easy starters ISPCONFIG but has its own challenges.
WEBMIN is not a hosting solution but a ADMIN web panel.

Or SENTORA https://zvps.uk/sentora/installer

Comment: I installed ISPConfig and I have another question for you. :) I guess it will be more easier that, I asked another question here https://superuser.com/questions/1235333/ispconfig-dns-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your entry for "naked domain" `A` record.
Without "the trailing dot" it is `A` rekord for `mydomain.com.mydomain.com.`.

**WRONG**
`mydomain.com 86400 IN A 123.456.789.20`
Corrected:
`mydomain.com. 86400 IN A 123.456.789.20`

Comment: thx, I changed it but still I cant send any mails.

Comment: 1) You have created MX record for `mail.mydomain.com` 2) Wait a little for DNS changes to propagate (to secondary DNS servers) 3) report exact error messages

Comment: I don't have any error messages, I guess, need some patience.

Comment: Which MTA/SMTP server do you use?  There are some server specific debug procedures.

Comment: Sorry but, I don't know exactly. I am trying to complete iRedMail Server guide which they shared.

Comment: How can i check that the informations u asked?

Comment: Usually it is enough to inspect SMTP server greeting message - `telnet localhost 25`