# ISPConfig DNS Settings

Tags: networking, dns, webserver

I was folling [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-debian-8-4-jessie-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-1/) guide for my website. I did all and now I have ISPConfig panel and roundcube mail. After that it said I should have ISPConfig3 acting as my name server to active mail server. And there is [another guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/ispconfig_dns_godaddy) for dns setting.

Here is my problem; in the second guide, there are 2 IPs like `64.25.171.8` and `64.25.171.9` Where did came from? Are there GoDaddy's DNS Servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these are custom name servers, not GoDaddy servers.

In the tutorial, GoDaddy's nameservers are *park27.secureserver.net* and *park28.secureserver.net*.

These IPs are for the custom nameservers *ns1.erikturk.com (64.25.171.8)* and *ns2.erikturk.com (64.25.171.9)*.

These are apparently the IPs of the servers running ISPConfig (which is being used to manage BIND, etc.) and providing authoritative DNS for the domains *erikturk.com* and *ifwolfpack.com*.

If you were running your own authoritative DNS, you would use your nameservers and their IP addresses.

And note that while it's not great practice, for custom DNS, you can get away with assigning the nameservers the same IP if you only have one (so *ns1.example.com* and *ns2.example.com* could both be routed to a single IP).

Comment: I dont have my own DNS, I found this, https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-run-your-own-dns-servers-primary-and-secondary-with-ispconfig-3-debian-squeeze for running my DNS but, I don't know should I or not? :) if you are right about "I can use same IP for both" I will not :D

Comment: Okay, online.net is not accept same IP

Comment: You should just be able to replace ns0.online.net and ns1.online.net with ns1.yourdomain.tld and ns2.yourdomain.tld (you can make ns1 and ns2 subdomains if you need to). As a last resort if *that* doesn't work, you can simply get two free domains from a dynamic DNS provider such as noip.com or afraid.org, run a dynamic client on your server and use those free addresses as your nameserver entries.

Answer (score 0):

These are two IP addresses the author has used on servers where ISPconfig is installed.
   You should use the IP addresses you have used in the first tutorial.

Note that the first tutorial uses private IP addresses which will not work for public DNS services (unless you setup port forwarding from one of your public IPs to your private IPs) as these have to be public IP addresses.